# How to get function return result?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, callback

I am developing a file reading service that look like this:

```
angular.factory('fileService', fileService);

function fileService($cordovaFile){
    var service = {
        readFile: readFile
    };

    return service;

    ///////////////

    function readFile(path, file){
        $cordovaFile.readAsText(path, file)
        .then(function (success) {
            console.log("read file success");
            console.log(success);
            return success;
        }, function (error) {
            alert("Fail to read file:"+error);
            console.log("Fail to read file");
            console.log(error);
            return false;
        });
    }
}
```

And then using it like this:

```
var data = fileService.readFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory,filename);
console.log(data) //return undefined
```

The problem is it fail to return the data. How can I get the data return back?

Comment: It seems like your `return service` jumps you out of the function before the `readFile` function can run. I also don't see how the dot notation on the function call works / but that may just be my misunderstanding...

Comment: @sheriffderek From my console log, it show that it is executing the code. But it is slower and after the execution console log of data variable.

Comment: You need to look up what _promises_ in Javascript are. The `$cordovaFile.readAsText()` method returns a promise, and they are asynchronous, meaning you cannot assume the code in the functions you pass to the `.then()` method on them will run immediately. If this doesn't make sense, look up how promises work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not actually returning any result from the readFile function. You are returning data from your callback functions but if you come to think of it...that result is returned to the function readFile itself and it stays inside that function. What you would want to do is return the whole result of the function readFile and then resolve the promise in the controller where you use it. Here is the code:

```
angular.factory('fileService', fileService);

function fileService($cordovaFile){
        var service = {
        readFile: readFile
    };

    return service;

    function readFile(path, file){
        return $cordovaFile.readAsText(path, file);
    }
}
```

And then you use it like this:

```
var data = fileService.readFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory,filename);
data.then(function (success) {
        // Do whatever you need to do with the result
    }, function (error) {
       /// Handle errors
    });
```

In general, when you use services to implement some kind of functionality that uses promises and returns result, you should always return the promise object which can be than resolved anywhere that it is needed.
I highly recommend that you read this great explanation for [promise objects](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Comment: @GregL Thanks for the notice. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `readFile` returns nothing, so, firstly you should be returning the promise:

```
function readFile(path, file) {
  return
    $cordovaFile.readAsText(path, file).then(function (success) {
      console.log('Read file success');
      console.log(success);
      return success;
    }, function (error) {
      alert('Fail to read file: ' + error);
      console.log('Fail to read file');
      console.log(error);
      return false;
    });
}
```

And then, if you try to use it the way you were, you'll not get undefined anymore, you'll get a promise.

But since it's an async method, you'll get that promise still pending, and you probably don't want that, since you'll need the promise's fulfilled value. So, you should use it like this:

```
fileService.readFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory, filename).then(function(data) {
  // use data here
});
```